# AG Grid React > ReactUI > Loading Bug?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm getting an odd behavior when trying to switch my React AG Grid to use the ReactUI param as described here: https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/reactui/#js-components-inside-react-ui

When I add the following to my AgGridReact component:

```
reactUi
```

The loaders I have setup using the following don't clear after the content is loaded:

```
components={{
  loadingRenderer: (params) => {
    if (params.value !== undefined) {
      return params.value
    } else {
      return '<img src="https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/loading.gif">'
    }
  }
}}
```

It works as expected if I remove the reactUi param.  Here is a plunker I have setup that illustrates the problem.

https://plnkr.co/edit/D2bKgj6USnIhO1Tj

Is there an alternative approach to setting up the loader or is this a bug in AG Grid?

**UPDATE:** Also posted this issue here: https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/4771

Comment: At the bottom of that document you linked to is "This is brand new, so there may be some teething problems." You may want to get in contact with AGGrid's support dept.

Comment: @Andy - Good call.  Just submitted an issue with AG Grid and linked it here as well.

Comment: Nice. I developed a very complex React app with AG a year ago and this update was news to me. Hope all goes well. I have nothing but praise for their support staff btw.